# How do I reduce Hamiltonian path to a weight-constrained Hamiltonian path?

Tags: complexity-theory, reduction

I have a problem, where you'd like to find a Hamiltonian path whose weight sum is more than or equal to half the total weight sum of a graph G=(V, E), to reduce by the help of usual Hamiltonian path.

How can I perform this? I am not sure about how I am supposed to do this, I am trying to write a reduction algorithm, but I am completely stuck right now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "weight sum?"

Comment: Given a hamiltonian path p, the sum of edge weights on p is more than or equal to half the total length of a grap G=(V, E). More clear?

Comment: That's what I meant with a Hamiltonian path that is "weight constrained". And this problem I want to reduce by the help of usual Hamiltonian path (that is, not weight constrained).

Comment: Edit: not "total length" as number of edges, it should the the total edge weight sum.

Comment: So you want a path whose weight is at least half of the sum of all the edge weights in the graph?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But since it is a matter of complexity classification, then I want to reduce the problem to find such a path by the help of the regular Hamiltonian path problem. And I want to write a reduction algorithm, but as mentioned, I am stuck. I don't know what techniques I should use to write such reduction algorithm.

Comment: Interesting, where does this problem come from?

Comment: It's from an school assignment I am working on. I have tried a lot, but I have been stuck for a while now, therefore the question here.